# Application Domain Design

Tags: design-patterns

I have a design level issue, I do not know how to solve this, but basically what i want to achieve is, I have a console based application which performs certain task based on a Input job (Which is a XML file, that consists of all the details to execute a job),and there is a web based application which creates a job.

Currently, we manually copy XML file and invoke the console based app by passing the XML file as a parameter.

Is there anyway i can design an application where all the jobs that have been created in web based application is passed to a queue.

There may be 2 hungry console based applications waiting for the jobs to be queued up (in a round robin fashion), as soon as they find a job it will start executing the job.

There is an other thing ,what i was thinking is there any way to technically i can control the number of console based applications from web site, let say i have 50 jobs sitting in queue and i can start 10 console based applications to work on the 50 jobs instead of 2, so this way the work can be completed.

Please let me know if you need any more information

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that as follows.

I have a windows service that is the orchestrator, which means, it uses Quartz.NET to schedule tasks. There are 4 types of tasks which are run at regular intervals:

- file registrator task: picks up new xml files and registers them in database
- batch loader: creates batch for registered files
- batch extracter: creates jobs for new batches
- job executor: executes jobs.

This windows service has no other logic than scheduling these tasks. The job executor task can even run multiple times in parallel.

The actual logic is in a (Batch Import) WCF service that is called from within the windows service. This way other applications like a admin web site are able to use the Batch Import WCF service, so that they can get a list of files, batches, progress etc, and allow manipulations on them.

Typical domain logic that is executed as a result oj job execution is done in dedicated domain services, called from the the Batch Import Service.

It's also possible to set properties to indicate whether steps should be automatic or manual, whether batches are transactional, and so on. It's quite flexible this way, and resumable in case something goes wrong because everything is persisted in a database with various states. It's also scalable: you can put everything on multiple machines, load balance the WCF services and execute jobs in parallel.